# training and evaluating an stacked auto-encoder model in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to train a model in pytorch.

input: 686-array
first layer: 64-array
second layer: 2-array
output: predition either 1 or 0

this is what I have so far:

```
class autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder_softmax = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(686, 256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(256, 2),
            nn.Softmax()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_softmax(x)
        return x

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

net = net.to(device)


iterations = 10
learning_rate = 0.98
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=1e-5)


for epoch in range(iterations):
    loss = 0.0
    print("train_dl len: ", len(train_dl))

    # net.train()
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dl, 0):
        inputs, labels, vectorize = data

        labels = labels.long().to(device)
        inputs = inputs.float().to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)

        train_loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        loss += train_loss.item()


    loss = loss / len(train_dl)
```

but when I train the model, the loss is not going down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try reducing the learning rate? how big is your training dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) as the loss function, which applies log-softmax, but you also apply softmax in the model:

```py
self.encoder_softmax = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(686, 256),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Linear(256, 2),
    nn.Softmax() # <- needs to be removed
)
```

The output of your model should be the raw logits, without the `nn.Softmax`.

You should also lower the learning rate, because a learning rate of 0.98 is very high, which makes the training much less stable and you'll likely see the loss oscillate. Are more appropriate learning rate would be in the magnitude of 0.01 or 0.001.